# How does one electroplate Lithium onto a conductive metal?

Tags: electrochemistry, electroplating

In this case the anode for electroplating would be the Lithium and the cathode would be any conductive metal.

Unfortunately Lithium reacts violently with water, which is the basis of most electrolyte solutions that are used for electroplating.

So is there an anhydrous electrolyte solution or an alternative method for electroplating Lithium onto a conductive metal?

Comment: Molten salt maybe?

Comment: Lithium hexafluorophosphate dissolved in dialkylcarbonate. That is bases of LiIon/LiPol cells. But it is highly flammable.

Comment: I'd rather use the ambient temperature molten salt ethylammonium nitrate. Easy to synthesized and no need for high temperatures. Thoughts?

Comment: Nitrate is oxidizing, maybe?

Comment: Ethylammonium is a weak acid. Lithium would not survive there. I would expect reactions: $$\ce{2 EtNH3+ + 2 Li -> 2 EtNH2 + 2 Li+  + H2}$$   $$\ce{2 EtNH2 + 2 Li -> 2 EtNHLi  + H2}$$ and reduction of nitrate. Additionally, there would be preferred $$\ce{2 EtNH3+ + 2e- -> 2 EtNH2 + H2}$$

Comment: I would expect lithium to react with ethylammonium nitrate more violently than with water. Additionally, an inert atmosphere is needed, as lithium reacts even with nitrogen.

Comment: Why alternative ? Note that even dialkylcarbonate very slowly react with lithium. But considering your estimated chemistry knowledge, I rather discourage you from such experiments.